# How to target new tab on response.redirect on just one button every click but not all the buttons, radio buttons..etc?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a problem with targeting a new tab. I came across this suggestion for Response.redirect() function, in order for a button to open a new tab, I can do this:

```
   OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';"
```

Which is right, it's doing is job. But now I'm on a dilemma, that every button I click after that, will be on a new tab. How to prevent this from happening? I know I can just assign this:

```
   OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_self';"
```

But how about radio buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not clear why you using client side code. I suppose you can.

You could use server side code, say this markup:

```
        <h3>My Cool menu based on Radio button list</h3>


        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" 
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="radionav"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged"
            AutoPostBack="true" >
                <asp:ListItem Value="~/Default.aspx">Default</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="~/Contact.aspx">Contact</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="~/About.aspx">About</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

And code behind is this:

```
Protected Sub RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim sURL = RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value
    Response.Redirect(sURL)

End Sub
```

So, we now get this:

[image]

However, I suppose in your case, if you want to use client side JavaScript, then use:

```
onclick="window.location.href = '../Default.aspx';return false;"
```

Note that some effort or better stated caution is required here when using .hef from JavaScript, as the path name used must be in relation to the current web page, and thus for example example, I was running the page in a folder called Test, and thus I have to step down one folder level (..) to then navigate to the Default.aspx page.

### Edit

The code behind does not have to navigate for all buttons as per my example, but you can check/test the index value, and ONLY navigate based on one of the options being selected.

Comment: This is not what I would like to achieve though. I would like to open that to a new tab and still retain the original page. I'm trying to prevent to cause a popup blocker. That's why I'm using response.redirect().

Comment: Well, opening a new tab? Not a good idea, since that tab means you now have 2 web pages open, and worse yet, there is ZERO connection between the 2 tabs, and you thus lose much of the UI control here.  If you need to pop open a dialog, then use a jQuery.UI dialog, as they can safely open a dialog to say allow editing in that popup. Try the example here that uses a dialog to edit say a record, and thus LITTLE reason to open a new tab. So try this idea:  http://www.kallal.ca/Website11/WebForm2